# Performance impact of having inner classes

Tags: java, performance, inner-classes, lombok, coding-efficiency

I would like to know if an inner class would have any impact on performance.
Currently I have a class as below.

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Sample {
    // A total of 9 fields
    // 1. long
    // 2. Enum
    // 3. long
    // 4. int
    // 5. Set<Long>
    // 6. long
    // 7. Enum
    // 8. double
    // 9. long
}
```

Currently I have just used lombok's `@Data` and `@AllArgsConstructor`. The use case is such that I would always have to use the all argument constructor while creating an object of this class.

If I am using `@Builder` annotation, that would create an inner class. (We have followed the builder pattern for creating objects in most cases).

**So in general, does having inner classes have any kind of impact on performance?**

Comment: What's the thinking that led to this question (or what made you suspect the potential for performance impact)? I'm curious - possibly because I don't see any obvious reason for it.

Comment: Worrying about performance before you are sure that there is a performance problem leads to bad design because of "premature optimization". So, choose the design that is most robust and easy to read, and worry about performance only if you encounter a problem (and don't blindly follow sonar, it's only a machine).

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff not just due to the sonar issue, I wanted to know in general, if it impacts the performance when there are inner classes. Like, if it does have an impact, then while migrating to cloud, if many of the classes are having inner classes, then that might increase the cost right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the JVM, there is no such thing as in "inner class", it's just a class (with a funny synthetic name) and (unless it's static) an additional field holding the outer `this` instance.

So, the performance impact of using an inner class instead of a stand-alone one should be hardly noticable.

But creating an instance to hold the call arguments for a method instead of calling the method directly with a long argument list, is inherently slower: you have to create an instance, initialize its fields with the intended method arguments, and the method has to retrieve the arguments from this instance, and finally this instance becomes garbage.

I agree that long argument lists are a code smell, but introducing a `MethodXyArguments` class doesn't improve anything, it just hides it under a carpet.